# logic to split and add digits to the assigned weights n SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the below requirement.
Below is the program.
I am not getting the expected out put.
Please correct me where I am going wrong.

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   5   0   8   0   0   2   0   0   4   0   0   4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   3   1   2   4   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
```

Assign weights  of 7, 5, 3, 2 from left to right:

```
7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   6   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   5   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3   2   7   5   3
```

Multiply each digit  by its assigned weight:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   7   25  0   16  0   0   6   0   0   20  0   0   24  0   0   2   0   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  6   7   10  12  0   7   5   0   2   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   7   5   0
```

Split and add digits:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   7   7   0   7   0   0   6   0   0   2   0   0   6   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   6   7   1   3   0   7   7   7   2   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   5   0
```

total is 104

Divide the sum by the Modulus 10:

104/10 = 10.4

Subtract remainder from Modulus 10:

10-4 = 6

Check digit:

6

Comment: the 21st digit = 7, weight = 4, so the product of digit x weight should be 28 not 24

Comment: will you care to explain the above logic Assign weights of 7, 5, 3, 2 ,then multiply and so on ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through your query as it can be done with set-based solution.
Don't need  cursor. Just use recursive to generate a number table. If you have a number table, use it

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '00000011150800200400400100004000000000431240110110000001110'

; with 
number as   -- replace with a number or tally table if you have one
(
    select  n = 1
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    number
    where   n   < len(@str)
),
weights as
(
    select  n = 1, weights = 7  union all
    select  n = 2, weights = 5  union all
    select  n = 3, weights = 3  union all
    select  n = 0, weights = 2
)
select  check_digit = 10 
                    - ( sum(s.d1 + s.d2) % 10 )
from    number n
        inner join weights w    on  n.n % 4 = w.n
        cross apply
        (
            select  d1 = convert(int, substring(@str, n.n, 1)) * w.weights / 10,
                    d2 = convert(int, substring(@str, n.n, 1)) * w.weights % 10
        ) s
```

You can verify the intermittent result with the following `select` clause

```
select  n.n, 
        digit = convert(int, substring(@str, n.n, 1)), 
        [weight] = w.weights,
        [digit x weight] = convert(int, substring(@str, n.n, 1)) * w.weights,
        s.d1, s.d2
```

Comment: I think the above function is calculating the sum in the 3 rd row which is 219. so 219/100=9 and 10-9 is 1. But  I want the split and add from the 3rd row in each cell. ex: if I have 25. I want 2+5=7     add the amounts from all cells and divide by 100.Divide the sum by the Modulus 10  
106/10 = 10.6  
Subtract remainder from Modulus 10  
10-6=4  
Check digit  
4  
Please suggest.

Comment: oh.. missed that logic. Will amend soon

Comment: I tried to call the above solution by declaring a function                            
      create Function [FN_checkdigit_tst](@str varchar(100)
Returns Int
As
Begin
Declare @RetVal as int  ; with 
number a......                             I get synatx error at with.Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client. Please suggest where I am wrong

Comment: I am able to call it in a function. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me. If there is any better solution please share.
I am calling another function that adds no splits in to the main function.
```

BEGIN
   DECLARE @iCursor INT,
           @aCursor Varchar,
           @cCursor_Value INT,
           @iValidation_Value INT,
           @isum INT
           --@jcursor INT

```
-- for 7
   SELECT @iCursor = 1
   SELECT @iValidation_Value = 0
   SELECT @isum = 0
   --SELECT @jcursor = 1

   WHILE @iCursor <= @p_iStr_Len
      BEGIN
         SELECT @cCursor_Value = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(@p_cValidation_Str,'M','4'),'m','4'), @iCursor, 1))
         --SELECT @cCursor_Value = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@p_cValidation_Str,'M','4'), @iCursor, 1))
         SELECT @iValidation_Value = (@cCursor_Value * 7)
         SELECT @iCursor = @iCursor + 4

       --WHILE @jcursor <= datalength(@iValidation_Value)
              select @isum= @isum + [frdmrpt].[FN_Sumofdigits](@iValidation_Value)
       --     BEGIN SELECT @isum = @isum + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@iValidation_Value),@jcursor,1))
       --     SET @jcursor = @jcursor+1
       --END

      END

--for 5

   SELECT @iCursor = 2
   SELECT @iValidation_Value = 0
   --SELECT @jcursor = 1

   WHILE @iCursor <= @p_iStr_Len
      BEGIN
         SELECT @cCursor_Value = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@p_cValidation_Str, @iCursor, 1))
         SELECT @iValidation_Value = (@cCursor_Value * 5)
         SELECT @iCursor = @iCursor + 4
         SELECT @isum= @isum + [frdmrpt].[FN_Sumofdigits](@iValidation_Value)

      END


--for 3
   SELECT @iCursor = 3
   SELECT @iValidation_Value = 0

   WHILE @iCursor <= @p_iStr_Len
      BEGIN
         SELECT @cCursor_Value = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@p_cValidation_Str, @iCursor, 1))
         SELECT @iValidation_Value = (@cCursor_Value * 3)
         SELECT @iCursor = @iCursor + 4
         SELECT @isum= @isum + [frdmrpt].[FN_Sumofdigits](@iValidation_Value)

      END



--for 2   
   SELECT @iCursor = 4
   SELECT @iValidation_Value = 0

   WHILE @iCursor <= @p_iStr_Len
      BEGIN
         SELECT @cCursor_Value = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@p_cValidation_Str, @iCursor, 1))
         SELECT @iValidation_Value = (@cCursor_Value * 2)
         SELECT @iCursor = @iCursor + 4
         SELECT @isum= @isum + [frdmrpt].[FN_Sumofdigits](@iValidation_Value)

      END



--RETURN ( @isum)


      IF @isum % 10 = 0
         SELECT @isum = 0
      ELSE
         SELECT @isum = 10 - (@isum % 10)

      RETURN (Replace(@p_cValidation_Str,'M',4) + Convert(char(1), @isum))
   END
```